# QGIS plugin to django (APP to webAPP)

Tags: qgis-plugins, pyqt, web

What is the best aproach to make a QGIS plugin using PyQt (PyQGIS), and use that same app and integrate with a django project, in order to put that app on the web with the minimum replicated code possible.

I understand that this question may be a little bit vague, but what I intend to know is the possible approaches to [developing web based applications using QT](https://forum.qt.io/topic/2157/developing-web-based-applications-using-qt) with python instead C++.

I have found this one possible aproach which is `QtWebKit`.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible with [`QWebView`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwebview.html) from `QtWebKit`. You can display arbitrary websites in a [`QWebView`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwebview.html) and you can even interact with them from QGIS:

**django_web_view.py**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from PyQt4.QtCore import Qt, QUrl, pyqtSlot
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import QWebView

class Django_Web_View(QWebView):

    def __init__ (self, parent = None):
        super(QWebView, self).__init__(parent)

        self.webFrame = self.page().mainFrame()

        self.webFrame.javaScriptWindowObjectCleared.connect(self.on_reload)
        self.webFrame.loadFinished.connect(self.on_load_finished)

        # the url to your django web app
        # website_url = QUrl("http://127.0.0.1:8000/")

        # a static webpage is used for testing purposes
        website_url = QUrl.fromLocalFile("‪C:/absolute/path/to/testpage.html")

        self.load(website_url)

    def on_reload(self):
        # send this instance to JS so that the on_text_change method is available
        self.webFrame.addToJavaScriptWindowObject("django_web_view", self)

    def on_load_finished(self):
        # you can execute JS functions and get a return value
        initial_text = self.webFrame.evaluateJavaScript("getText()")

        # prints Alpha
        print initial_text.toString()

        # you can execute JS functions and pass arguments
        # e.g. change the input text to Beta
        self.webFrame.evaluateJavaScript("setText('Beta')")

    @pyqtSlot(str)
    def on_text_change(self, text):
        # prints whatever you enter in the HTML text input
        print text


if __name__ == "__main__": 
    a = QApplication([])

    hello = Django_Web_View()
    hello.show()

    a.exec_()
```

**testpage.html** (as an example of how your rendered Django webpage could look like)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<input type="text" id="textInput" value="Alpha"/>

<script>
    var textInput = document.getElementById("textInput");

    textInput.addEventListener("keyup", onTextChange);

    function setText(text) {
        textInput.value = text;
    }

    function getText() {
        return textInput.value;
    }

    function onTextChange() {
        var text = getText();
        django_web_view.on_text_change(text);
    }
</script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Copy the files to your filesystem, adjust the path to testpage.html and run `python django_web_view.py` in the command line. Python needs to be included in your PATH and PyQt4 needs to be installed for this python version (it is already installed in QGIS' python by default). Once you finished testing, you can add the modified django_web_view.py to your python QGIS plugin.